# Genymotion emulator only takes landscape photos

Tags: android, bitmap, genymotion

When I take a picture with webcam as the Android genymotion camera, the picture is rotated when in Portrait mode.

When I rotate the phone I can see Landscape photos.

When I load an image into my app, the width is always > than the height in the Bitmap.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I cannot speak regarding Genymotion, but "the width is always > than the height in the Bitmap" is common with real Android hardware. In those cases, the EXIF orientation header is set to tell you to rotate the image. Many developers use image-loading logic that ignores this header.

Comment: The EXIF header always shows 0!

Comment: Then perhaps you are hitting some limitation with Genymotion itself.